# JFreeChart NoClassDefFoundError on Windows Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jfreechart

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart

On Windows, a GUI system is always available.

Why such error still occur on Windows?

How to solve?

I use tomcat 7 with JFreeChart 1.0.14.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have library file of jfree in your classpath.

If you are using maven adding this dependency shall work,

```
<dependency>
<groupId>jfree</groupId>
<artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
<version>1.0.14</version>
```

Comment: I use maven 3. In my pom.xml file, there exist this fragment, but the error still occur in Windows Tomcat 7.

Comment: Please try changing version attribute to 1.0.13

Answer (score 0):

Its not an issue of windows, make sure you are including the jar of jfreechart in your classpath, if you are using maven use

```
<dependency> 
 <groupId>jfree</groupId> 
 <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId> 
 <version>1.0.13</version> <!--Use any valid version-->
</dependency>
```

If not using maven, downlaod the jar and add to your lib folder